# Use of "." vs. "," in Snowflake SQL JOIN ... USING() column list

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake (ANSI) SQL, I was surprised to find that

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  t1
INNER JOIN
  t2
USING(a. b, c)
```

compiled fine (I was thinking the `.` after `a` would cause a SQL compilation error). At a glance it looks like the result is identical to the same code with `USING(a, b, c)`. Also, `USING(a, b. c)` compiles and produces a different result, and `USING(a. b. c)` gives a SQL compilation error.

Anyone have an explanation for this behavior? How is SQL interpreting the `.` in the column list for `USING` here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "a. b" === "a.b".

I have tested below:

```
create or replace table t1 (a int, b int, c int);

select t1. a, t1.   c from t1;
select t1.a, t1.c from t1;
```

Both of above SELECT statement returned the same result.

This means in your example:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  t1
INNER JOIN
  t2
USING(a. b, c)
```

It is the same as :

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  t1
INNER JOIN
  t2
USING(a.b, c)
```

USING(a. b. c) failed because a.b.c does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent find, I too cannot find documentation on it but I did experiment further and found some interesting behaviour.

```
    with t1 as (
select 1 as a
  , 2 as b
  , 3 as c
)
, t2 as (
select 1 as a
  , 5 as b
  , 6 as c
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  t1
INNER JOIN
  t2
USING(a, b, c);
```

Produces a match for all

[image]

But as you manipulate the code as you did `USING(a. b, c)`
it puts the A at the end and the column appears twice!

[image]

When I change the the values in the columns and keep the dot where it is the output is... nothing

```
with t1 as (
select 1 as a
  , 2 as b
  , 3 as c
)
, t2 as (
select 1 as a
  , 5 as b
  , 6 as c
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  t1
INNER JOIN
  t2
USING(a. b, c);
```

Now change it up a bit more

```
with t1 as (
select 1 as a
  , 2 as b
  , 3 as c
)
, t2 as (
select 4 as a
  , 2 as b
  , 3 as c
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  t1
INNER JOIN
  t2
USING(a. b, c);
```

B and C should match but A does not
Non matching column appears twice

[image]

Beginning to see a pattern here right?

It seems that columns without the dot is used in the join, but the other column is not. Seems like you can only use one column with the dot notation, adding more dotted columns failed in error.

Answer (score 0):

The Dot Notation accepts spaces between the table name and the column name. I tested on Oracle and PostgreSQL. So this is a valid usage:

```
select 1 as a
  , 2 as b
  , 3 as c
)
select t1. a, t1.a from t1;

+---+---+
| A | A |
+---+---+
| 1 | 1 |
+---+---+
```

As far I see,  other databases do not accept dot notation in the USING clause, while Snowflake ignores the table name and gets the column name (*even if the table name/alias does not exist*). So when you write "USING (a.b, c)" - it just uses b and c columns to join the tables.

Why doesn't it support 2 level dot notation if it supports dot notation?

```
create or replace table t1 (a int, b int, c int) as select 1,2,3;
create or replace table t2 (a int, b int, c int) as select 1,2,3;
select public.t1.a from t1; -- works

select *
from  t1 join t2
using( public.t1.a ); -- fails
```

This is inconsistent with the previous behaviour. The correct behaviour should be "not accepting any dots" as the other database vendors do. Can you report it as a bug?

Comment: Thanks Gokhan, I confirmed this inconsistency in my own DB as well -- submitted a community post here (https://community.snowflake.com/s/feed/0D53r0000AwRC8HCQW)